# example for calculation of the exterior derivative

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

I don't understand how to calculate exterior derivatives. For the form
$$
    \theta = \frac{x\, dy - y\, dx}{x^2 + y^2}
$$
I arrive at the following solution:
$$
\begin{align*}
    d\theta
    &= d\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right) \wedge dy
     + d\left(\frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}\right) \wedge dx \\
    &= \frac{-x^2 + y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} dx \wedge dy
     - \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}dy \wedge dx \\
    &= 0.
\end{align*}
$$
I don't understand the second step. Or also in these examples [Exterior Derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2882472/709467)
I don't see how we get the solutions.

I know that $df_p$ is a function from $T_pM$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
But here we don't have a specific point $p$ and I don't think I can use this definition to calculate the exterior derivative of $x/(x^2 + y^2)$. Is there another definition for $df$?

I was also wondering if there are general rules that could help with this kind of calculations (such as $dx \wedge dx = 0$).

Comment: I just realised that $d(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}) = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}) dx$. But I don't understand why we can do this.

Comment: what examples of exterior derivatives calculation do you know?? do you know the definition of exterior derivative?

Comment: The definition I have is $d: \Omega^k(M)\to \Omega^{k+1}(M)$ with $d(\sum \omega_Idx^I) := \sum d\omega_I\wedge dx^I$ but this only helps with the first step in the example.

Comment: for a function $\omega_I$ you mentioned above, what is $d\omega_I$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read definition of exterior derivative.

Consider the manifold $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differential $0$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  The exterior derivative of $f$ is a differential $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Recall that, a differential $1$ form is an expression of the form $$\sum_{i=1}^n g_i dx_i$$ where $g_i:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is a smooth map. So, for $f$, the exterior derivative $df$ is defined as $$\sum_{i=1}^n g_i dx_i$$ where $g_i$ is the $i^{th}$ partial derivative of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Is it clear till here?

Comment: Yes, for 1-forms I see how it's done. I think part of the problem was the sum over $d\omega_I$, as you said in the comments.

Comment: But $\omega_I$ is also of the form $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.. Isn't it? What ever I have mentioned for $f$, that is $df$, should be carried to do for $\omega_I$, that is d\omega_I$... Do you see any problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you apply the definition you have:
$$
\begin{align*}
    d\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right) \wedge dy
    &= \partial_x\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right) dx \wedge dy
     + \partial_y\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right) dy \wedge dy \\
    &= \partial_x\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right) dx \wedge dy \\
    &= \frac{-x^2 + y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} dx \wedge dy
\end{align*}
$$
I'll let you conclude the exercise.

Comment: How do you get this using the definition of $df_p$ ?

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind as "definition of $df_p$". Take a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative